# windows phone 8.1 html taqs rss app

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I want to ask is there any way to remove the html taq from Rss Reader on windows phone 8.1 I'm working on app that show the topics on any site using Rss on the smartphone " windows phone" but I have this problem can I remove the html taqs
this pic will show u what I mean ??
[image: the problem remove the html taqs]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What control is this? Have you consider using a Web Browser control? Or, if you really need to display it in a TextBox (assuming it's a TextBox), you can convert your HTML into a XAML FlowDocument, using this [tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2006/05/25/606317.aspx).

Comment: For example i got that data from a lot of website not my website

Comment: @MrEko please update your question with some code. Which controls are you using? How do you feed those controls with external data?

Answer (score 0):

I follow the same tutorial for create my rss reader.
So, for remove the html code you need create a class to trimmer the description:
Create a class named RssTextTrimmer.cs with the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using System.Net;

namespace VEJA_Notícias
{
public class RssTextTrimmer : IValueConverter
{


    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;

        int maxLength = 200;
        int strLength = 0;
        string fixedString = "";

        // Remove HTML tags. 
        fixedString = Regex.Replace(value.ToString(), "<[^>]+>", string.Empty);
        // Remove newline characters.
        fixedString = fixedString.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "");

        // Remove encoded HTML characters.
        fixedString = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(fixedString);

        strLength = fixedString.ToString().Length;

        // Some feed management tools include an image tag in the Description field of an RSS feed, 
        // so even if the Description field (and thus, the Summary property) is not populated, it could still contain HTML. 
        // Due to this, after we strip tags from the string, we should return null if there is nothing left in the resulting string. 
        if (strLength == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        // Truncate the text if it is too long. 
        else if (strLength >= maxLength)
        {
            fixedString = fixedString.Substring(0, maxLength);

            // Unless we take the next step, the string truncation could occur in the middle of a word.
            // Using LastIndexOf we can find the last space character in the string and truncate there. 
            fixedString = fixedString.Substring(0, fixedString.LastIndexOf(" "));
        }

        fixedString += "...";

        return fixedString;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
}
```

And in your MainPage.xaml you need add the code:

```
<Page.Resources>        
    <local:RssTextTrimmer  x:Key="RssTextTrimmer" />
</Page.Resources>
```

To access the method of RssTextTrimmer class in the xaml textblock you need to do so:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textTitulo" Text="{Binding title, Converter={StaticResource RssTextTrimmer}}"/>
```